# converting ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 in servlet response

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have a servlet which retrieves data from an Oracle database. The encoding in the database is Latin1. Following code works fine for the browser:

```
resp.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
resp.getWriter().write(result);
```

but I need to be able to return UTF-8, like so:

```
utfResult = ???;
resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
resp.getWriter().write(utfResult);
```

In order to achieve this I have tried many syntaxes, none of which worked.

The system is Tomcat 7 on Java 7. Thank you for your support.

To answer to the request for more detail:

with the first version, all the characters appear fine in the browser but not in the NodeJS program which uses the data.

when I replace the `resp.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-1");` with `resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` the character öäüèéà are replaced by ?

Comment: Please elaborate the concrete problem in detail. Which characters exactly do you have and how exactly do they appear in the result after your attempt. You namely don't need to manipulate the `result` at all (unless your DB is *actually* not in ISO-8859-1). Just setting the response encoding has been sufficient.

Comment: that is what you should be doing.  what is the error you are seeing?  (note, you don't need to do anything to result).

Comment: The encoding in the database should be irrelevant to the encoding you send the data to the client in. Once you've retrieved the information from the database as a `String`, the database really doesn't matter.

Comment: Once the data is retrieved from the database, it is in an internal Java encoding. It should automatically convert to the specified output character set encoding.

Comment: So, the original result is in ISO, you want to encode it in UTF-8?

Comment: *"the character öäüèéà are replaced by ?"* This is impossible when ISO-8859-1 data is written as UTF-8. But it can happen when UTF-8 data is written as ISO-8859-1. This is thus not a problem in servlet side, assuming that the information provided so far is correct. An SSCCE would be helpful. In the meanwhile, reading [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) should give new insights in the world of characters and bytes.

Comment: On the other hand, this can also be a misinterpretation of the whole process under the covers. For example, you've at some point used `System.out.println()` to "debug" the characters and are incorrectly basing your observation on it instead of the actual response body.

Answer (score 0):

Java `String` is already Unicode text. So the only problem might be that the reading from the database could have gone wrong. Check that.